# How to change from UISearchDisplayController deprecated in iOS 8.0 to UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I used `UISearchController` since learning that `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated. But now have a problem, integrating with [SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete](https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete/issues/20) forked library by Chenyuan in GitHub.

I get the search bar when I start typing no results are displayed. What I am also wondering is if UISearchDisplayController is deprecated how, come Chenyuan Demo run without warning or issue of deprecated methods.

Here is my code snippet which I attempted to convert his demo to UISearchController, please tell me where I'm going wrong.

MainViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
@class SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,
UISearchBarDelegate,
UISearchControllerDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSArray *searchResultPlaces;
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *searchQuery;
    MKPointAnnotation *selectedPlaceAnnotation;

    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;

@private
    CGRect _searchTableViewRect;
}

// Search
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKLocalSearch *localSearch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKLocalSearchResponse *results;

@end
```

MainViewController.m snippet

```
  // setup Search Controller
-(void) setupSearchController {

    // The TableViewController used to display the results of a search
    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    searchResultsController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; // Remove table view insets
    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    // Initialize our UISearchController
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    // Hint for the search

    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search your destination address";

}

// Setup Search Bar
-(void) setupSearchBar {

    // Set search bar dimension and position
    CGRect searchBarFrame = self.searchController.searchBar.frame;
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchBarFrame.origin.x,
                                                       searchBarFrame.origin.y,
                                                       viewFrame.size.width,
                                                       44.0);

    // Add SearchController's search bar to our view and bring it to front
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.searchController.searchBar];

}
```

continuation of the MainViewController.m

```
-(void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)aSearchController {

    aSearchController.searchBar.bounds = CGRectInset(aSearchController.searchBar.frame, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Set the position of the result's table view below the status bar and search bar
    // Use of instance variable to do it only once, otherwise it goes down at every search request
    if (CGRectIsEmpty(_searchTableViewRect)) {
        CGRect tableViewFrame = ((UITableViewController *)aSearchController.searchResultsController).tableView
        .frame;
        tableViewFrame.origin.y = tableViewFrame.origin.y + 64; //status bar (20) + nav bar (44)
        tableViewFrame.size.height =  tableViewFrame.size.height;

        _searchTableViewRect = tableViewFrame;
    }

    [((UITableViewController *)aSearchController.searchResultsController).tableView setFrame:_searchTableViewRect];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayDelegate

- (void)handleSearchForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    searchQuery.location = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    searchQuery.input = searchString;
    [searchQuery fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not fetch Places"
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            searchResultPlaces = places;
            // [self.searchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
            [[(UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController tableView] reloadData];
        }
    }];
}

- (BOOL)searchController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self handleSearchForSearchString:searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // User tapped the 'clear' button.
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        [self.searchController setActive:NO];
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
    }
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (shouldBeginEditing) {
        // Animate in the table view.
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        // self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.alpha = 0.75;
        [(UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController tableView].alpha = 0.75;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    }
    BOOL boolToReturn = shouldBeginEditing;
    shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [searchResultPlaces count];
}

- (SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *)placeAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return searchResultPlaces[indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath].name;
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)recenterMapToPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = placemark.location.coordinate;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
}

- (void)addPlacemarkAnnotationToMap:(CLPlacemark *)placemark addressString:(NSString *)address {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];

    selectedPlaceAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    selectedPlaceAnnotation.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate;
    selectedPlaceAnnotation.title = address;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not map selected Place"
                                                            message:error.localizedDescription
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        } else if (placemark) {
            [self addPlacemarkAnnotationToMap:placemark addressString:addressString];
            [self recenterMapToPlacemark:placemark];
            [self requestForwardGeoCoding:[self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath].name];
            // ref: https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete/issues/10
            [self.searchController setActive:NO];
            // [self.searchController.searchResultsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        }
    }];



}

@end
```

[image: My Error in attempt to convert to UISearchController]

[image: App screenshot with no results predictions from google places api]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [UISearchResultsUpdating](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchResultsUpdating_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchResultsUpdating) protocol.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <..., UISearchResultsUpdating>
.
.
.
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // Filter results and reload table data
}

-(void) setupSearchController {
    .
    .
    .
    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
}
```

(as an aside, putting Google place results onto an Apple map is a violation of Google's terms of use, I believe).